# How to get the smallest date from a list of objects with a date?

Tags: c#, .net

I created a simple class that represents a project:

```
public class EntityAuftrag
{
    public string cis_auftrag { get; set; }
    public string bezeich { get; set; }
    public DateTime? dStart { get; set; }
    public DateTime? dEnd { get; set; }
    public decimal? aufstunde { get; set; }
    public int id_auftrag { get; set; }
    public string barcolor { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have a list of these. I want to extract the smallest date, how do I do that?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can use [`Enumerable.Min`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.min.aspx) (`null` values will be ignored unless all values are null):

```
DateTime? smallest = auftragList.Min(a => a.dStart);
```

**Edit**: if you want to find the object with the earliest(start) date, you can use `OrderBy` and `First`:

```
EntityAuftrag auft = auftragList.OrderBy(a => a.dStart).First();
```

If you want the latest date, you can use `Enumerable.OrderByDescending` instead.

Comment: It is worth nothing that `Min` appears to automatically discount null values.

Answer (score 4):

you can use the Min() LINQ extension method:

`collection.Min(item => item.dStart);`

I see your date property is nullable, so if you want to avoid nulls, use the following:

`collection.Where(item=> dStart.HasValue).Min(item => item.dStart);`

Comment: `Min` appears to avoid nulls anyway, so the latter example is not needed.

Comment: thanks for the correction Adam.
but anyhow, when you query your data it's null isn't always welcome :)

Answer (score 3):

You can do that simply with Linq. Given that you want the object with the earliest `dStart`, you can do the following:

```
List<EntityAuftrag> list = someSourceOfItems;

EntityAuftrag firstObject = list.OrderBy( i => i.dStart ).First() as EntityAuftrag;
```

Alternatively (not sure if the above is the right syntax), you can do it this way:

```
List<EntityAuftrag> list = someSourceOfItems;

EntityAuftrag firstObject = (from item in list
                            orderby item.dStart
                            select item).Single() as EntityAuftrag;
```

Enjoy your day :-)